# Rails application Error with Nginx/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I just made the Capistrano deployment to a server with Linux Server (14.04), Nginx, PHP5-FPM (for phpMyAdmin), MySQL, Passenger.

Everything is fine, but when I try to access the rails app from the browser I get error. I went to check the Log Nginx and I get the following:

```
App 15973 stdout: 
App 15973 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (deploy) and Ruby interpreter...
App 15973 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 15973 stderr:      Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
App 15973 stderr:      /tmp/passenger_native_support-a97tab.log
App 15973 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] not downloading because passenger wasn't installed from a release package
App 15973 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
App 15973 stderr:   --> Passenger will still operate normally.
App 16021 stdout:
```

Then:

```
$cat /tmp/passenger_native_support-a97tab.log

# current user is: deploy
# mkdir -p /usr/lib/buildout/ruby/ruby-2.2.1-x86_64-linux
Encountered permission error, trying a different directory...
-------------------------------
# mkdir -p /home/deploy/.passenger/native_support/5.0.26/ruby-2.2.1-x86_64-linux
# cd /home/deploy/.passenger/native_support/5.0.26/ruby-2.2.1-x86_64-linux
# /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby /usr/lib/src/ruby_native_extension/extconf.rb
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/lib/src/ruby_native_extension/extconf.rb (LoadError)
```

What's wrong with it?

This is my Nginx Default file:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    # root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    development;
        root         /home/deploy/highschool/current/public;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And my Nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##

    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

    # passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I use **RBENV** for Ruby versions.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue from last 1 week.

Comment: I ran into this exact same issue with a fresh install today using https://github.com/sandrew/from-scratch. Turned out passenger was still trying to use passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby; as I had it defined twice. Not sure if that was all I did, but once I removed the dual entry and rebooted everything started to work.

Comment: @CoryLoken 
I managed to correct the error and raise my application.

Comment: @ShubhamAbrol
I managed to correct the error and raise my application.

Comment: I was getting the error because there was an error in my SASS file and my SECRET_KEY was also not configured with the devise. But after deep debugging and checking the nginx+passenger logs for hours I found these two errors  . Now I have fixed those errors and everything is running properly.

Comment: There is a bug in 5.0.26 that causes this, which is slated to be fixed in 5.0.27. Follow along here: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1778

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

In my server, I ran the following command into my Rails App: `$ passenger-config build-native-support`.
That compiled correctly and show me the really path of `ruby_native_extension/extconf.rb` or `ruby_native_extension` directory.

I only create a symbolic link from `/usr/lib/src/` to `ruby_native_extension` directory and restart Nginx.

When I did that the error disappeared , but then the Login ( devise ) did not work , always got the 404 error .
So, (if in any case happens) I added some lines specifically for the route sign_in.

In my Nginx Default file I added the following:

```
location /users/sign_in {
  passenger_enabled on
}
```

And edit:

```
location / {
   # First attempt to serve request as file, then
   # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
   passenger_enabled on
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

And with these changes, my rails application is running.